# execute oracle function with an out parameter of rowtype with php

Tags: php, oracle, execute, rowtype

I have an oracle function which has an out parameter which is of table rowtype as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function retrive_emp
(
emp_id in integer;
rec_emp out tablename%rowtype;
.
.
.
```

I want to execute this function in php and my question is how to bind the out

.............

I tried below:

I have a boolean parameter so I used:

```
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":isAbsent", $isAbsent,OCI_B_BOL );
```

and for the rowtype parameter I used

```
      oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":rec_emp", $rec_emp,-1, OCI_B_BIN );
```

but I still get the error:

Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: row 1 ، column 15 : PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments

Can anyone tell me what I am  doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think [This article](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/fuecks-sps.html) along with [Php Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) hold the answer to your question.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried some things as  the two links you provided but it still doesn't work , can you tell what am I doing wrong here? I edited my question to show what I've tried

Comment: It looks like you dont need to bind by name the `rec_emp out tablename%rowtype`. One of the examples in manual implies that. But that is a big assumption, the error tells there is wrong number of params, and by the looks of it only one param should be binded

Comment: can you please tell me which example (I noticed the row type and I used both SQLT_BIN and OCI_B_BIN and they did not work), and there is no error in the number of the params , the error is in the type of the params, example above is just sth I made up but in my real case I checked from the number of params and I am still struggling with binding those two types(boolean and rowtype)  Thank you for your help ,, I appreciate it

Comment: there is a `Example #11 Binding parameters for a PL/SQL stored procedure` there. However I cannot say for certain that it suits you. As I undestand, the example implies that `oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":rec_emp", $rec_emp,-1, OCI_B_BIN );` should not happen, because it's an out param